# Spyder Unresponsive

Tags: python, spyder

so I am using Spyder IDE for python. it stopped executing my codes, I have tried to run only a few lines and all together but still no response.
Anyone familiar with these sort of issues?

```
#Assinging Variables
ProductName = "iPhone"
ProductPrice = 450
Tax = 0.5 #Tax is a constant that cannot be changed

print(ProductTax)


#Dealing with Inputs

name = input("Your Name")
print(name)

print("Hello", name)

city = input("Where do you live?")

print(name, "lives in", city)

#CASTING - converting one data type to another as examples below.

##Note that all the answers required below will be in form of strings
ProductName = input("what is the product Name?") 
ProductPrice = float(input("how much is it cost?")) #the string is converted to float
ProductQuantity = int(input("How many?")) #the string is converted to an integer

TotalPrice = ProductQuantity*ProductPrice
print("Total Price: ", TotalPrice)


##SELECTION
## selection is used to choose between 2 or more otions in programming
## if statements is a type of 'selection'

#weather = input("is it raining")
#if weather == "raining":
    #print ("Grab an Umbrella")
#else:print("Wear a coat")
```

Answer (score 0):

it works for me when create a new Console. Hope that works for you.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsfek.png)